# Adding controls to page on PreRender

Tags: asp.net, events

Do you know any drawback to add controls to a page on PreRender event?
please don't answer 'depends on your case' I'm talking in general:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `PreRender` event happens after control events, so the control could not use any events.

If you for example add a `Button` in `Page_PreRender`, it's too late to hook up a `Click` event handler for it. At postack the button would not be recreated until after the click event had already been handled (and ignored).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, see this link for the ASP.NET lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

I would recommend adding controls on the `Init` event as the new control would otherwise be cleared on any postbacks. This is as per https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx.

'Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin settings have been applied. Use this event to read or initialize control properties.'